# Disable radio buttons after set as buttonset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 radio buttons

```
<div id="test">
<input type="radio" id="time1" name="radio" value="1" /><label for="time1">Test 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="time2" name="radio" value="2" /><label for="time2">Test 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="time3" name="radio" value="3" /><label for="time3">Test 3</label>
</div>
```

in jquery

```
$("#test").buttonset();
```

**After that**, I want to disable them with (of course, the disabling are placed in an `if` statement)

```
$("#test input").attr("disabled", true);  //or
$("#test input").prop("disabled", true);
```

but it not works, the buttons are still enabled.

Comment: Your <input> tags are missing last letter.

Comment: @MichaelSwan check my DEMO link, it seems work

Comment: it is occured because $.buttonset(). after disable radio call it again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#test > input:radio").button({disabled:true});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/amutum/6/edit)**

Comment: _"$("#test input").prop("disabled", true);
but it not works, the buttons are still enabled."_ you just copied his not working code...

Comment: It looks like you copy answers. :(

Comment: @gdoron I don't copy answer and I think SO is not a place for Copy/Paste practice.  :(

Answer (score 11):

You're using jQuery-UI, after you change the radio buttons to `buttonset`, they are no longer effect the UserInterface, as it's wrapped with:

```
<div id="test" class="ui-buttonset">
<input type="radio" id="time1" name="radio" value="1" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="time1" aria-pressed="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Test 1</span></label>
<input type="radio" id="time2" name="radio" value="2" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="time2" aria-pressed="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Test 2</span></label>
<input type="radio" id="time3" name="radio" value="3" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="time3" aria-pressed="true" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right ui-state-active" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Test 3</span></label>
</div>
```

So you need jQuery UI function to disable the "buttons" (which are `spans`!)

```
$("#test input").button("disable")
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P3Faw/2/)

[jQuery-UI source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#method-disable)

Answer (score 1):

after disable call $("#test").buttonset() again.

```
$("#test").buttonset();
```

then:

```
$("#test input").attr("disabled", true);  //or
$("#test input").prop("disabled", true);
$("#test").buttonset();
```

i test it and work for me

Comment: It's a very expensive operation, you should use jQuery UI native fucntions. You can see in my answer what the `buttonset` function does...

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this, according to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/#method-refresh) is:

$( '#test' ).buttonset( 'option', 'disabled', true ).buttonset( 'refresh' );

I could not get any of the other suggestion to work. This one does, for me.

Answer (score 0):

The method which I use is (the Radio Group ID is the buttonset ID) :

```
$('#RadioGroupID').buttonset('disable').buttonset('refresh');
```

Now, supposing you wanted to set one of the radio buttons to being selected, trigger a click event you may have programmed to the relevant radio button and then disable, you can chain all of this as follows:

```
$('#RadioButtonID').prop('checked',true).trigger('click').parent().buttonset('disable').buttonset('refresh');
```